# retrieve page ids of member without manage page permissions

Tags: facebook-page, accounts

can anybody tell me if its possible to retrieve a list of a member's pages without manage pages permissions? or if its possible to send the graph a facebook page id and have it return whether or not the current FB user admins the page.

i have a page tab application which a FB user can install to one of their pages, and in order to show the relevant info regarding the current FB user from my website on their facebook page, i need to know that the page they have given me is administered by them.

since i dont want any control over the page itself, only to know that the page id ive received is associated with the current FB user, asking for permissions to log in as any and all of their facebook pages seems like a bit of an excessive permission